productbuild create an .pkg that install in the current directory, not the `install-path`
productbuild --sign "Developer ID Installer:" --component MyApp.app /Applications/ MyApp.pkg

When running MyApp.pkg MyApp.app will be installed in the current directory, but not in /Applications/ like I explicitly mentioned as parameter (install-path)
To make it work I need to first move MyApp.app to /Applications/ and then run
productbuild --sign "Developer ID Installer:" --component /Applications/MyApp.app MyApp.pkg
Here I get a valid installer with the appropriate behavior but I should be able to get that same installer using the first command at the beginning of this post but this doesn't work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Could you solve your issue? I have the same problem.
